# C#, Throws error what trying to get value from two dimensional array and uses it in TryParse

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
private static char[,] boardValues = {
    {'1', '2', '3'},
    {'4', '5', '6'},
    {'7', '8', '9'}
};

public static bool SetPlayerLocation(int[] location, char character)
{
    // check if slot is taken
    if (byte.TryParse(boardValues[location[0],location[1]], out _))
    {
        boardValues[location[0], location[1]] = character;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This keeps throwing the error, cannot convert from '`char`' to '`System.ReadOnlySpan<char>`', on the line of the `if` statement.

Comment: There's [no overload of `byte.TryParse` which takes a `char`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.byte.tryparse?view=net-5.0). You probably need to turn it into a string first: `byte.TryParse(boardValues[...].ToString(), out _)`

Comment: But, would it be better to just check if the char is between 0 and 9? `if (boardValues[...] is >='0' and <='9')`

Comment: To convert a char 0-9 to int 0-9 you can subtract `0x30` from the char

Comment: @CaiusJard Yep, although it's easier to subtract '0' from it

Comment: Hah, yea, I forget these things. Only one more keypress though :D

Comment: @canton7 the `.ToString()` worked, thanks alot

Comment: @CaiusJard what do you mean by subtract `0x30`

Comment: I looked at the TryParse and assumed you were trying to convert e.g. a char `'0'` to a number `0`, so I pointed out you can do that conversion simply by subtracting 0x30 (the hex code of a '0', which I find easier to remember than decimal 48, because 0x30 and 0 both end in 0, the hex code for '7' is 0x37 etc..). Then Anthony pointed out that it's even easier to just subtract '0'...

Comment: All in, it's probably easiest to just use `if(Char.IsDigit(boardValues[location[0],location[1]]))` for this, but bear in mind if you have e.g. `'7'` char and want `7` int, then you can: `char c = '7'; int seven = c - '0';`

Comment: Aha yes, `char.IsDigit` is better than any of my suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never said what you use to mean by "taken" but it looks like it might be "a char between `'0'` and `'9'`" - maybe a slot that is "not taken" has a space `' '` or `'x'` in it.. or similar..

So this code you have seems, essentially, to check the presence of a numeric and for that I would instead recommend:

```
private static char[,] boardValues = {
    {'1', '2', '3'},
    {'4', '5', '6'},
    {'7', '8', '9'}
};

public static bool SetPlayerLocation(int[] location, char character)
{
    var slotTaken = Char.IsDigit(boardValues[location[0],location[1]]);

    if (slotTaken)
        boardValues[location[0], location[1]] = character;
    
    return slotTaken;
}
```

If we make the code a bit more self documenting with a reasonable variable name, we can do away with the comment..

..which then makes me wonder if the logic is really correct - if a slot is taken, then you're allowed to replace it?

Should the variable be called `slotFree` ? Should the `if` be `if(!slotTaken)`, or is it truly correct that players may only occupy taken slots? Only you know this, but it's a good intro to hw creating self-documenting, readable code can help inform someone else reading it (the person who takes over your job when you leave :D ) or find bugs

Comment: Was just checking whether the character at that location is numerical (e.g '0', '1', etc) or is the values 'X', or 'O'. the `Char.isDigit()` method solved the problem